# IZpack - how to install JRE using IZPack?

Tags: java, izpack

I am creating JAVA swing application. Goal is to make that application installable and distributed in for of exe or JAR, which is to be installed in different windows based machines.
I am using IZpack for this purpose.

My Problem is the swing application itself needs JRE. So, how can is install JRE on client PC using IZpack ?

Thanks

Comment: Provide an executable that runs the installer if a JVM is present and displays an appropriate message if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with IZpack on its own, but you can wrap up an IZpack installer JAR as a `.exe` using a tool such as [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net), and when users run the `.exe` it will prompt them to download a JRE if there is no suitable one installed already.